# Rally update Changeset data from Java using Java Toolkit for Rally REST API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I need to create a new Changeset entry for a story, given I have the formattedID and the objectID for the story. 
I am using the given Java Toolkit for Rally REST API (http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api)

Any help here would be very useful thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a example of how to accomplish this:

```
public class RestExample_AddChangesetToUserStory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        // Rally parameters
        String rallyURL = new String("https://rally1.rallydev.com");
        String wsapiVersion = new String("1.36");
        String userName = new String("user@company.com");
        String userPassword = new String("password");
        String applicationName = new String("RestExample_AddChangeSetToStory");

        // Workspace and Project refs
        String workspaceRef = new String("/workspace/12345678910");
        String projectRef = new String("/project/12345678911");

        // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                                                    new URI(rallyURL), 
                                                    userName,
                                                    userPassword
                                                );
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);

        // Changeset Owner Username
        String changesetOwner = new String("changesetowner@company.com");

        // SCM Repository Name
        String scmRepositoryName = new String("SVNRepository");

        // FormattedID of Artifact to associate to
        String storyFormattedID = "US14";

        //Read User
        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", changesetOwner));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();        
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").toString();
        System.out.println("userRef: " + userRef);

        // Query for SCMRepository which pertains to this ChangeSet
        QueryRequest scmRequest = new QueryRequest("SCMRepository");
        scmRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ObjectID","Name","SCMType"));
        scmRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        scmRequest.setProject(projectRef);
        scmRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", scmRepositoryName));
        QueryResponse scmQueryResponse = restApi.query(scmRequest);
        JsonObject scmJsonObject = scmQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String scmRef = scmJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();
        System.out.println("scmRef: " + scmRef);

        // Query for Story to which we want to add ChangeSet
        QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Changesets"));
        storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", storyFormattedID));
        storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        storyRequest.setProject(projectRef);
        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
        JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray changesetJsonArray = storyJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Changesets");
        String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();

        System.out.println("storyRef: " + storyRef);
        System.out.println("Number of existing Changesets: " + changesetJsonArray.size());

        // Setup JsonObject for new Changeset
        JsonObject newChangeset = new JsonObject();
        newChangeset.addProperty("SCMRepository", scmRef);
        newChangeset.addProperty("Author", userRef);
        newChangeset.addProperty("Revision", "2451");
        newChangeset.addProperty("Uri", "https://svnrepo.company.com:8001");
        newChangeset.addProperty("CommitTimestamp", "2012-07-18T18:00Z");
        // Artifacts JsonArray for collection on Changeset
        JsonArray artifactsJsonArray = new JsonArray();
        artifactsJsonArray.add(storyJsonObject);

        // Associate newChangeset to Story artifact
        newChangeset.add("Artifacts", artifactsJsonArray);

        try {

            //Create the Changeset
            System.out.println("Creating Changeset...");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("Changeset", newChangeset);
            System.out.println(createRequest.getBody());
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

            if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));
                String[] warningList;
                warningList = createResponse.getWarnings();
                for (int i=0;i<warningList.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(warningList[i]);
                }
            } else {
                String[] errorList;
                errorList = createResponse.getErrors();
                for (int i=0;i<errorList.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(errorList[i]);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your response it has helped a lot, the only problem i am facing is that i am getting an error saying:

Could not set value for Artifacts: Cannot connect object to value, Artifacts value is in a different workspace. [object workspace OID=5103, value workspace OID=127336

Comment: Your User Story (or any artifact for that matter) has to be in the same Workspace as the one containing the SCM Repository and Build definition. As a general rule, you cannot cross workspaces when manipulating data in Rally.

Comment: Ok i understand, is there any way that i can check the SCM Repository that is being used in the Artifact's workspace. i.e. what is the SCM Repo for this artifact? Many thanks for your help

Comment: The SCM Repository is defined for the Workspace. SCM functionality was designed for Rally source code connectors which interact using webservices API, so getting this data from the user interface isn't readily apparent. You can query for the available SCM Repositories in your Workspace using the Webservices API docs. Here's a video illustrating how to do this: `http://screencast.com/t/HBdsMU1Wo`. Make sure to navigate to the Workspace that contains your user stories of interest before running the query.

Comment: If your Workspace has no SCM Repositories defined you'll need to make sure that Build Definitions and Changesets are enabled for the Workspace (must be an Administrator to do this), and then you must create a new SCM Repository using REST - you can't create it in the Rally UI.

Comment: Yes I've just made one and it worked great! thank you for all your help