# Using C# Rally RestApi to Add and Update Rally Item ChangeSets

Tags: c#, rest, rally

We are a shop that uses C# , Team Foundation Server and Rally as our main item tracking.

We would like to use Rally Item ChangeSets to follow TFS Changesets.  Using Rally's C# RestApi seems a little different than the one made in Java.

Is there a way to do the same thing as described in this article using the Rally C# RestApi?
[Rally update Changeset data from Java using Java Toolkit for Rally REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521986/rally-update-changeset-data-from-java-using-java-toolkit-for-rally-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do the same in .NET. A perk is that it's a lot less verbose than the Java equivalent. Here's an example:

```
// System Libraries
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

// Rally REST API Libraries
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace RestExample_AddChangesetToUserStory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set user parameters
            String userName = "user@company.com";
            String userPassword = "topsecret";

            // Set Rally parameters
            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String rallyWSAPIVersion = "1.40";

            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi(userName,
                                       userPassword,
                                       rallyURL,
                                       rallyWSAPIVersion);

            // Changeset Owner Username
            String changesetOwner = "scm_integration@company.com";

            // SCM Repository Name
            String scmRepositoryName = "MySCMRepo";

            // FormattedID of Artifact to associate to
            String storyFormattedID = "US14";

            // Create Request for User
            Request userRequest = new Request("user");
            userRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "UserName",
                    "Subscription",
                    "DisplayName"                    
                };

            // Add a Query to the Request
            userRequest.Query = new Query("UserName", Query.Operator.Equals, changesetOwner);

            // Query Rally
            QueryResult queryUserResults = restApi.Query(userRequest);

            // Grab resulting User object and Ref
            DynamicJsonObject myUser = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myUser = queryUserResults.Results.First();
            String myUserRef = myUser["_ref"];

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345678910";
            String projectRef = "/project/12345678911";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            // Get handle to SCM Repository
            Request scmRequest = new Request("SCMRepository");
            scmRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "ObjectID",
                    "Name",
                    "SCMType"
                };

            // Add query
            scmRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, scmRepositoryName);

            // Query Rally
            QueryResult querySCMResults = restApi.Query(scmRequest);
            DynamicJsonObject myRepository = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myRepository = querySCMResults.Results.First();

            // Find User Story that we want to add Changeset to

            // Tee up Story Request
            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;

            // Fields to Fetch
            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Changesets"
                };

            // Add a query
            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, storyFormattedID);

            // Query Rally for the Story
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            // Pull reference off of Story fetch
            var storyObject = queryResult.Results.First();
            String storyReference = storyObject["_ref"];

            // Pull existing Changesets off of Story
            var existingChangesets = storyObject["Changesets"];

            Console.WriteLine("Story: " + storyFormattedID);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Existing Changesets: " + existingChangesets.Count);

            // DynamicJSONObject for New Changeset
            DynamicJsonObject newChangeset = new DynamicJsonObject();

            // Commit Time Stamp
            String commitTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

            // Populate Changeset Attributes
            newChangeset["SCMRepository"] = myRepository;
            newChangeset["Author"] = myUserRef;
            newChangeset["Revision"] = "2451";
            newChangeset["Uri"] = "https://svnrepo.company.com:8001";
            newChangeset["CommitTimestamp"] = commitTimeStamp;

            // Artifacts list
            var changeSetArtifacts = new ArrayList();
            changeSetArtifacts.Add(storyObject);

            // Update attribute on Changeset
            newChangeset["Artifacts"] = changeSetArtifacts;


            try
            {
                // Create the Changeset
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Rally Changeset...");
                CreateResult myChangesetCreateResult = restApi.Create("ChangeSet", newChangeset);
                String myChangesetRef = myChangesetCreateResult.Reference;
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully Created Rally Changeset: " + myChangesetRef);

                List<string> createWarnings = myChangesetCreateResult.Warnings;
                for (int i = 0; i < createWarnings.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(createWarnings[i]);
                }

                List<string> createErrors = myChangesetCreateResult.Errors;
                for (int i = 0; i < createErrors.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(createErrors[i]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred creating Rally Changeset: " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```