# how to read changeset for perticular user story and update the build column using REST API- java?

Tags: rally, code-rally

currently i'm looking for solution to read and update the user story changesets using Rally java  REST Api.
how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sharan,

This previous post may be a good starting point:

[Rally update Changeset data from Java using Java Toolkit for Rally REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521986/rally-update-changeset-data-from-java-using-java-toolkit-for-rally-rest-api)

EDIT:

Sharan,

I did some fiddling around and found that I could not update the Builds on Changeset, but I could add a Changeset to a Build.

You'll need to know the _ref URL for the Build and Changeset you want to use, but then it is pretty straight forward.  I used Apache HTTP Client to do the operations below.  The header, 'zsessionid' is your API Key for Authentication.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String jsonString = "{\"Build\":{\"Changesets\": {\"Changeset\":\"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/changeset/123456\"}}}";

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/build/123456");
        postRequest.setHeader("zsessionid", "_ApIK3y");
        postRequest.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: basically i want to update this build column.by reading the change sets for user story.examples shows how to create change set.

Comment: You mean the 'builds' column, right?  Maybe a little more detail will help.

Comment: That sounded harsh and I didn't mean it to...you want to add or remove entries in the Builds collection or you want to edit info about a particular build?